# What is the font used in the www.whitehouse.gov Presidential portraits?

Tags: font-identification

What is the nice Times-like font used in the Presidential portraits [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/1600/presidents)? WhatTheFont gets me close but doesn't quite match. Example with a 3 and an 8: [Gerry](https://www.whitehouse.gov/1600/presidents/geraldford).

[image: Gerry]

Comment: The text above and below the image? You can inspect a website and check what fonts it uses: `font-family: "Hoefler Text A","Hoefler Text B",Georgia,"Times New Roman","DejaVu Serif",serif;`

Comment: Do you actually need the source font or are you just wanting to create another presidential image and number it? If the latter then you could extract the numbers and fake it.

Comment: The text in the image. But I see now that it's probably the same as the webpage text around the image. So I'll go that route. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is: Hoefler Text [Source](http://www.typography.com/fonts/hoefler-text/overview/)

I inspected the font element in order to find this. It said:

font-family: "Hoefler Text A","Hoefler Text B",Georgia,"Times New Roman","DejaVu Serif",serif;

Downloading the font would be violating the font usage subscription service they have set up for webfonts.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't accept 3 years ago... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the name of the fonts used on the site but I can show you a way to download them!

### Follow the steps

---

1. In Chrome right click on the page and select "**Inspect Elements**"
2. Select **Resources Tab**
3. Expand the "**Frames**" folder till you can find "**Fonts**"

That's it! The listed fonts are used in the website! You can download them also! Just right click on each item and open link in new Tab!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Patrick. In this case, unfortunately, the glyphs are rendered into the images themselves.